# Does anyone know the Data transfer type for RDP connections to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to estimate data transfer pricing on AWS, but I'm confused by the distinction of:

`Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet`

and

`Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Using a public or Elastic IP address`

Is this the difference of calling by IP`(http://54.128.10.9)` vs. using DNS`(http://ec2-54-128-10-9@aws.com)`?
The above IP and DNS are made up for this question.

The first costs $.12/GB while the second is only $.01/GB so it's a big difference.  Also, can anyone tell me if an RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) is any different than a standard http call?  I wouldn't think so, but would love to hear from someone who's been billed for this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the difference here is that

`Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet` represent any data that goes outside of EC2. This is any protocol: HTTP, TCP, RDP, etc.

`Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Using a public or Elastic IP address` that you mention in reality is data transfer within EC2. If you use an internal IP address you don't get charged anything. However, if you use and elastic or public IP (This includes using the public DNS name) you get charged $.01/GB. Check the image below:

[image: AWS Data Transfer rates]

So I believe if you are sending data outside of AWS the billing that you care is `Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet` at $0.12/GB for up to 10TB /month, $0.09/GB for the next 40TB and so forth...

The difference between HTTP and RDP is just simply different protocols. If you look at the network stack they both happen to run on top of TCP.

> Additional comments:

Public or Elastic IP address data transfer doesn't have to be within EC2.  If you happen to do that, meaning transferring data within EC2 using public IP addresses (in other words the public cloud) Amazon will charge you something (less than EC2 traffic to another Cloud Provider for example). Note that if you use private addresses within a Region Amazon doesn't charge you anything. Notice that you can't do data transfer using private addresses across regions.

Comment: Thank you, that was a great answer!  Looking at the chart now it makes sense, but I was having trouble getting the light bulb to go off.

Comment: I can see why an Elastic IP address is within EC2, but why is a public address data transfer within EC2 ?

Comment: @mcmillab Check my "Additional comments"